# Correct use of std::cout.precision() - not printing trailing zeros

Tags: c++, floating-point-precision

I see many questions about the precision number for floating point numbers but specifically I want to know why this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
  int a = 5;
  int b = 10;
  std::cout.precision(4);
  std::cout << (float)a/(float)b << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

shows `0.5`? I expect to see `0.5000`. 
Is it because of the original integer data types?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iomanip>
int main()
{
  int a = 5;
  int b = 10;
  std::cout << std::fixed;
  std::cout << std::setprecision(4);
  std::cout << (float)a/(float)b << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

You need to pass `std::fixed` manipulator to `cout` in order to show trailing zeroes.

Answer (score 6):

`std::cout.precision(4);` tells the **maximum number of digits to use** not the minimum. 
that means, for example, if you use

```
precision 4 on 1.23456 you get 1.235  
precision 5 on 1.23456 you get 1.2346
```

If you want to get `n` digits at all times you would have to use `std::fixed`.

Comment: There's a small mistake here I think. Instead of printing `1.234` or `1.2345`, it would round the last digit and print `1.235` and `1.2346`.

Answer (score 2):

The behavior is correct. The argument specifies the maximum meaningful amount of digits to use. It is not a minimum. If only zeroes follow, they are not printed because zeroes at the end of a decimal part are not meaningful. If you want the zeroes printed, then you need to set appropriate flags:

```
std::cout.setf(std::ios::fixed, std::ios::floatfield);
```

This sets the notation to "fixed", which prints all digits.

Comment: can you elaborate please these `fixed` and `floatfield` especially `floatfield`. is ther any other way to achieve it. like  `std::cout.setf(std::ios::right);`  is equivalent to `std::cout <<std::right;`

Comment: I think I got it. it's equivalent to `std::cout<<std::fixed;` what you are explaining is achieved by `showpoint` which is used for printing trailing zeroes.