# Precision in double and other floating numbers

Tags: c++, precision

I am having trouble getting my program to output the correct precision for my doubles. Say I have a

```
double d;
```

After running some algorithm, I get `d` as my output. I want to set the precision of my `d` variable to 4 points of precision after decimal. I should be able to do this like so:

```
cout << setprecision(4) << d;
```

The problem is that if I if `d` is an integer, then no decimal placed are printed.

For example, if `d == 120`, then my program will print `120`. I want it to print `120.0000` instead. How do I get my program to always print 4 decimal places?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Correct use of std::cout.precision() - not printing trailing zeros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341870/correct-use-of-stdcout-precision-not-printing-trailing-zeros)

Comment: Why was this question down-voted so much?  Isn't it perfectly clear and valid?  It has been asked (probably more than once) before, however.

Answer (score 3):

You need to be using fixed precision to output a fixed number of decimal points. You should to tell the stdout stream (`cout`) that you want to use fixed precision.

```
std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(4) << d;
```