# Why Template Function call is ambiguous?

Tags: c++, templates

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template <typename T>
T max(T x, T y)
{
    return (x > y) ? x : y;
}
int main()
{
    cout << max(3, 7) << std::endl;
    cout << max(3.0, 7.0) << std::endl;
    cout << max(3, 7.0) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I'm Expecting max's Instance here

```
cout << max(3, 7) << std::endl; // max (int, int)
cout << max(3.0, 7.0) << std::endl; // max (double, double)
cout << max(3, 7.0) << std::endl; // max(int, double)
```

Then what is the problem ? Why I'm getting

`11 25  [Error] call of overloaded 'max(double, double)' is ambiguous`

Comment: You should try again without `using namespace std` to remove a source of confusion.

Comment: @juanchopanza still same..

Comment: Do it anyway. Fix your code and post the error message.

Comment: @juanchopanza `11 28 Desktop\Objects.cpp [Error] no matching function for call to 'max(int, double)'
`

Comment: @LetDoit That is not the same error as "call of overloaded max is ambiguous"!

Comment: Wouldn't the `typename T` be common to the first and the second argument, thereby making the definition `max(int, double)` not possible?

Comment: @LetDoit That is because you two need two different template parameters as you are using two different types.

Comment: @NathanOliver Great..!!

Comment: Yet another mess caused by `using namespace std;`.

Comment: @NathanOliver here is the code http://codepaste.net/rkh612 why I'm not getting correct output?

Comment: @LetDoit `cout` is truncating the decimal part as it adds nothing.  see: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/961547c050a01ccc

Comment: @NathanOliver so what is the solution?

Comment: @LetDoit There is a thing out there called google that has a lot of information.  If you googled `cout traling zeros` you would get http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341870/correct-use-of-stdcout-precision-not-printing-trailing-zeros

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you view the compile error in full, you'd see why. Here's what gcc 5.2 gives me:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:10:21: error: call of overloaded 'max(int, int)' is ambiguous
     cout << max(3, 7) << std::endl;
                     ^
main.cpp:4:3: note: candidate: T max(T, T) [with T = int]
 T max(T x, T y)
   ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/5.2.0/bits/char_traits.h:39:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/5.2.0/ios:40,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/5.2.0/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/5.2.0/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/c++/5.2.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:219:5: note: candidate: constexpr const _Tp& std::max(const _Tp&, const _Tp&) [with _Tp = int]
     max(const _Tp& __a, const _Tp& __b)
     ^
```

Basically, there are two `max` functions - yours and [`std::max`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max), which is included by some chain of other `#include`s from `<iostream>`. The latter is found by lookup because of your

```
using namespace std;
```

Effectively, we have:

```
template <typename T> T max(T, T);                      // yours
template <typename T> T const& max(T const&, T const&); // std
```

Neither is better than the other, hence ambiguous. This is a great reason to [avoid `using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/2069064). Or a great reason to not reinvent the wheel when it comes to standard library functions - just use `std::max`. Or both.

---

On the other hand, this one

```
max(3, 7.0)
```

will fail regardless as a template deduction failure. It would deduce `T` as `int` for the first argument, and `T` as `double` for the second - but there can only be one `T`! You would have to explicitly call either `max<int>(3, 7.0)` or `max<double>(3, 7.0)` to get around the deduction failure, depending on which of the two arguments you want to cast.

Comment: which is best compiler? I heard allot about GCC how to download and use it?

Comment: @LetDoit There is no best compiler. I just presented sample output to indicate that compiler output is valuable. If you want to use gcc, you can just google gcc.

Comment: @LetDoit Why do you think you're getting the incorrect output? That prints `7` three times.

Comment: I'm expecting about `7.0`

Comment: @LetDoit Wrong expectation.

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
using namespace std;
```

makes things complicated, for sure. However, even after you remove that line, the problem continues to exist.

The call `max(3, 7.0)` can be resolved to `max<int>` or `max<double>`. To resolve to `max<int>` a `double` has to be converted to an `int`. To resolve to `max<double>`, an `int` has to be converted to a `double`. Since both require a conversion and one conversion cannot be given higher priority than the other, the compiler is not able to resolve which one to use.

You'll have to be explicit which version of `max` you want to use.

`max<int>(3, 7.0)` will convert `7.0`, a `double`, to an `int`.

`max<double>(3, 7.0)` will convert `3`, an `int`, to a `double`.

Answer (score 0):

Max is a library function.just change the max identifier for your function to max1 or any other name that is not a function defined any header files.
That should solve your problem.

Comment: Please, try to format your answer in such a way that it clearly distinguishes code examples from prose. You can enclose code using backticks (`).