# How can I truncate in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I want to do convert Fahrenheit to Celsius and I use the formula 
I put 
cout.setf(ios::fixed);
cout.precision(0); // because I want the result to be a whole number

```
float c;
float f;
c = 5.0/9.0*(f-32)

cout << "Enter Fahrenheit":
cin >> f;
cout << "Celsius"
     << c
      << endl;
```

Please, I need help is for my homework, thanks.

Comment: Probably not a duplicate, but should be at least helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554063/how-do-i-print-a-double-value-with-full-precision-using-cout

Comment: Also maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341870/correct-use-of-stdcout-precision-not-printing-trailing-zeros

Comment: You seem to be running your conversion **before** knowing what `f` is. Maybe try moving it underneath the `cin` line.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to **truncate** the value, use a cast:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    float f;
    std::cout << "Enter Fahrenheit: ";
    std::cin >> f;
    float c = 5.0f / 9.0f * (f - 32.f);
    std::cout << "Celsius: "
              << static_cast<int>(c)
              << '\n';
}
```

if you however want to round the value:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    float f;
    std::cout << "Enter Fahrenheit: ";
    std::cin >> f;
    float c = 5.0f / 9.0f * (f - 32.f);
    std::cout << "Celsius: "
              << std::round(c)
              << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Thanks soooo much, it really helped me!