# Dividing an integer with a double

Tags: c++, double, division

I have a really easy question.

```
    std::cout << std::setprecision(2);
    for (int i = 3; i > 0; i--) {
       std::cout << i / 3.0 << " ";
    }
```

The above code gives the output:

```
1 0.67 0.33
```

Why does `i = 3` return an integer number, but `i = 2` and `i = 1` return a double number? The precision is set to `2` and we are dividing by a double, so I'm confused.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct use of std::cout.precision() - not printing trailing zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341870/correct-use-of-stdcout-precision-not-printing-trailing-zeros)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`setprecision(n);` tells the maximum number `n` of digits to use, not the minimum. Keep in mind that trailing zeroes are automatically discarded, this is what happens when you divide 3 by 3.0, the result is 1.000... but the zeroes get discarded. If you want to get `n` digits at all times you have to use `std::fixed` like this:

```
cout << fixed;
cout << setprecision(2);
```

and it will give you 2 digits, so for instance `3 / 3.0` will yield `1.00`.